# Smart Polling using RxAndroid

Tags: rx-java, polling, rx-android

What I want to achieve:
I want to poll some resources from the web by polling every 5 minutes but only when there is an observer subscribed. I use BehaviorSubject and interval observable for pooling. I managed to implement it but I'm new to Rx and I think it can be done better.

This is how i've done it:

```
private BehaviorSubject<String> observable;
private Subscription> subscription;

public Subscription subscribe(final Action1<String> action) {
    if (observable == null) {
        observable = BehaviorSubject.create();
    }
    if (subscription == null) {
        Observable<String> source = Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).map(new Func1<Long, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Long aLong) {
                return getDataFromServer();
            }
        }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        subscription = source.subscribe(new Action1<String>() {

            @Override
            public void call(String s) {
                if (observable.hasObservers()) {
                    observable.onNext(s);
                } else {
                    subscription.unsubscribe();
                    subscription = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return observable.subscribe(action);
}
```

The idea:
- I have an observable source for polling and another observable to which the clients can subscribe (implemented using BehaviourSubject - so they always get the latest data). When the source observable emits something if the behavioursubject has subscribers it is passed on, otherwise nothing is passed and I unsubscribe from the source so it will stop.

Comment: Take a look at how I did polling here: http://orbyt.github.io/RxCookbook/. after the `.interval()` operator, I used the `.takeWhile(boolean)` operator to toggle it on and off. Not sure if its a good fit for what your trying to accomplish, but let me know if it helps.

Comment: i ca'nt find any takeWhile operator in your example

Comment: Thats because its not there, I listed how to use the `.takeWhile()` operator in my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about:

```
Observable<String> observable = Observable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .doOnNext(new LoggingAction1<Long>("doOnNext"))
    .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<String> call(Long pulse) {
            return Observable.just(String.format("Request %d", pulse));
        }
    })
    .replay(1)
    .refCount();
```

I think it does all you want your setup to do:

- As long as there are no `Subscribers` it does nothing.
- When the first `Subscriber` subscribes, the `interval` is started and emits one value right away and then one every 5 seconds.
- A new `Subscriber` will get the last item right away and then all following ones.
- Only one `interval` will be started - and therefore only one network request will be executed every 5 seconds - no matter how many `Subscribers` there are.
- When all `Subscribers` have unsubscribed, the `interval` will stop emitting items.